# sql error with [ in table name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysqli code:

```
SELECT aircraft.*, [users_storage].*
FROM aircraft_database aircraft,
     `[users_storage]` userstorage
WHERE aircraft.aircraftid = userstorage.aircraft
  AND userstorage.userid = '1'
```

where the tables used is `[users_storage]` and `aircraft`

I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '[users_storage].* FROM aircraft_database aircraft,
>   `[users_storage]` userstorag' at line 1

This occurs when using `[` and `]` in table names.

How can I make this query work?

Comment: Simply remove those. (You may use back-ticks instead.) ANSI SQL has double quoes, but some products have their own ways...

Comment: Why you need `[]` in your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table name is `[users_storage]` then you have to use backticks to properly delimit the name in the alias definition. Then simply use the alias in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT aircraft.*, userstorage.* 
FROM aircraft_database aircraft
JOIN `[users_storage]` userstorage 
   ON aircraft.aircraftid = userstorage.aircraft
WHERE userstorage.userid = '1'
```

If, on the other hand, you table name is `users_storage`, then you don't have to use backticks at all:

```
SELECT aircraft.*, userstorage.* 
FROM aircraft_database aircraft
JOIN users_storage userstorage 
   ON aircraft.aircraftid = userstorage.aircraft
WHERE userstorage.userid = '1'
```

**Note:** Use modern, *explicit* instead of *implicit* `JOIN` syntax.